# How to create a REST request using the Shopify Node JS API for a Private App?

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I'm trying to use the Shopify API to query all the orders of a selected Shopify store, using the private app instead of the OAUTH method. Below I have added the code, can't seem to figure out how to get it to work cause there isn't much documentation for the use of the private apps. Does anyone know how I can achieve this or has done this before? I think I maybe wrong but there maybe an error in creating the session.

Upon running the below code I get the below error:
`Error: Missing adapter implementation for 'abstractRuntimeString' - make sure to import the appropriate adapter for your platform`

```
const { shopifyApi, ApiVersion, Session, LATEST_API_VERSION } = require('@shopify/shopify-api');
const { randomUUID } = require('crypto');
const { restResources } = require('@shopify/shopify-api/rest/admin/2022-10');


const selectedStore = {
shop: "store.myshopify.com",
api_secret: "",
api_key: "",
private_admin_key: ""
};

const shopify = shopifyApi({
    apiKey: selectedStore.api_key,
    apiSecretKey: selectedStore.api_secret,
    scopes: ['read_orders', 'read_analytics', 'read_customers'],
    hostName: '<ngrok_url>',
    apiVersion: LATEST_API_VERSION,
    isEmbeddedApp: false,
    isPrivateApp: true,
    restResources
});

const session = new Session({
    id: randomUUID(),
    state: 'state',
    shop: selectedStore.shop,
    accessToken: selectedStore.private_admin_key,
    isOnline: true,
})

console.log(session)

const getOrders = async () => {
    const orders = await shopify.rest.Order.all({
        session,
        status: "all"
    })
    return orders
}

getOrders()
```

Answer (score 1):

In regards to the following errors:

```
Error: Missing adapter implementation for 'abstractRuntimeString' - make sure to import the appropriate adapter for your platform
```

You will need to add the following line

```
import '@shopify/shopify-api/adapters/node'
```

Before

```
import ... from '@shopify/shopify-api'
```

This is only lightly touched upon in their [migration guide](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/blob/16730c53b496ea9b575536e2c55f890aed58c882/docs/example-migration-v5-node-template-to-v6.md#4-create-a-new-file-called-shopifyjs)

Shopify developer experience with this library has definitely been rough

Source: https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-api-js/issues/400#issuecomment-1363021024

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Auth Token from a private App (inside the Shopify Admin), with permissions to read orders, you make a call to the Shopify store using that token. Look up the **end point** you call. Formulate your call. Make a GET or POST. Nothing hard to do there. Shopify assumes you know how to make a GET request with JS. Provide the Auth Token you gave yourself, and you'll get back all the orders you asked for. You cannot skip out on learning paging etc.. but again, that is also pretty standard stuff not special to Shopify.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response do you know of any way to do this through the Shopify library, I am familiar with the REST API approach and was able to get that to work but was wondering whether there is a method to do this using the library instead

Comment: I have no idea what the Shopify library is. Sorry. I know Shopify well, but I have never heard of the library!